Issues with internet connection via openvpn
The organization I'm with uses an OpenVPN connection and RDP to log into a virtual environment we work with. The way I understand it only traffic that is aimed at our internal net (in the 10.0.0.0/8 space) uses the VPN connection, everything else ignores it - at least that's how it works on Windows.
Up until now I've just used a Windows in dual boot with Linux, but now want to transition to Linux fully, but when I try the same there (Arch with Plasma 6, importing the VPN config in System Settings and activating the connection via rightclick -> connect) it seems like everything goes through the VPN - some sites are completely unreachable (eg. Microsoft, DuckDuckGo, etc.), while others have no issue at all (eg. Google or Wikipedia).
The connection per se works - logging into my virtual machine via KRDP immediately worked - so the only remaining issue that remains is getting only the RDP traffic routed through the VPN.
